# About SpringBoot Tomcat acceptCount pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, configuration

I'm dealing with the Tomcat configuration on springboot.

Let's supposse i have the following configuration:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    min-spare-threads: ${min-tomcat-threads:20}
    max-threads: ${max-tomcat-threads:20}
    accept-count: ${accept-concurrent-queue:1}
    max-connections: ${max-tomcat-connections:100}
```

I have a simple RestController with this code:

```
    public String request(@Valid @RequestBody Info info) {
        
        log.info("Thread sleeping");
          
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        
        return "OK";

    }
```

Then i make the following test:

1. I send 200 HTTP request per second.
2. I check the log and as I expected I see 100 simultaneous executions and after 8 seconds I see the last one (queued).
3. Other executions are rejected.

The main problem that i have with this is that if i have a timeout control on client call (for example, 5 seconds), the queued operation will be processed on server anyways even if it was rejected on client.
I want to avoid this situation, so I tried:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    min-spare-threads: ${min-tomcat-threads:20}
    max-threads: ${max-tomcat-threads:20}
    accept-count: ${accept-concurrent-queue:0}
    max-connections: ${max-tomcat-connections:100}
```

But this "0" is totally ignored (i think in this case it means "infinite").
So, my question is:
¿Is it possible to configure Tomcat to don't queue operations if the max-connections limit is reached?
Or maybe
¿Is it possible to configure Tomcat to reject any operation queued?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the [acceptCount](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) parameter is passed directly to the operating system: e.g. for UNIX-es it is passed to `listen`. Since an incoming connection is always put in the OS queue before the JVM accepts it, values lower than `1` make no sense. Tomcat explicitly ignores such values and keeps its default `100`.

However, the real queue in Tomcat are the connections that where accepted from the OS queue, but are not being processed due to a lack of processing threads (`maxThreads`). You might have at most `maxConnections - maxThreads + 1` such connections. In your case it's 81 connections waiting to be processed.